# How to describe making sounds with your throat?

Tags: word-choice, onomatopoeia, sounds

Say if someone asked you a yes/no question, and you make that note of assent with your throat to let them know that yes is the answer to the question, how would you describe that through writing? I don't just want to say 'She made a note of assent' or whatever... Is there an actual descriptive word, or onomatopoeic word I can use?

Comment: If you're looking for an adjective the most appropriate word is 'guttural'

Answer (score 3):

Grunt

"She made a grunt of assent"

Comment: Or "She grunted her assent".

Comment: *Growl* is also used for less passive grunts.

Answer (score 3):

**1. "Uh–huh"** (open mouth)

> interjection \two əm's or two ən's separated by the voiceless sound h; ˈəⁿ-(ˌ)həⁿ, (ˌ)əⁿ-ˈ\
>
> Definition of UH-HUH
>
> —used to indicate affirmation, agreement, or gratification
>
> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uh-huh

**2."Mmm-hmm"** (closed mouth)

Comment: Yes. And the second syllable is stressed, usually with a rising _intonation_ http://i.word.com/idictionary/intonation

Answer (score 3):

[Guttural](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/guttural)

adjective

1. of or relating to the throat.
2. harsh; throaty.
3. Phonetics. pertaining
   to or characterized by a sound articulated in the back of the mouth,
   as the non-English velar fricative sound

"She made a guttural reply"

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting with Google Ngram, and trying "* of assent,* of dissent"-- the machine suggests that ["murmur of assent"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+of+assent&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C*%20of%20assent%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmurmur%20of%20assent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmanifestation%20of%20assent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnod%20of%20assent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsign%20of%20assent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bact%20of%20assent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmurmurs%20of%20assent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgesture%20of%20assent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bexpression%20of%20assent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdegree%20of%20assent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchorus%20of%20assent%3B%2Cc0) is the big winner here.

I have to +1 "grunt" as suggested above, and "growl," and "sigh" and whatever other sound or gesture seems appropriate.

Comment: A murmur of assent is given by a crowd; not an individual.