# What's the name of this sound/collection of sounds?

Tags: grammar, american-english, sounds

What is it called when one expresses "Yes", "No", or "I Don't Know" without using words - just humming their response?  You know, when someone responds with a low note than a high note for Yes or "Ah-huh!"; a low note and a slightly lower note for No or "Nuh-uh"; or a low note, a high note, and a low note for I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

In a sentence, it's often called a *grunt* or *murmur of assent*.

A related question is [How to describe making sounds with your throat?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258516/how-to-describe-making-sounds-with-your-throat)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the word falls into the category of paralanguage. 
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/paralanguage

Answer (score -1):

[Wikipedia describes '**Vocables**'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocable) as "utterances which are not considered words."

> #### vocable n.
>
> A syllable or sound without lexical or referential meaning, vocalized as part of a song or sung melody.
>   - [OED Definition 2](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/224261?isAdvanced=false&result=1&rskey=EVGlsm&)

Comment: This would be an excellent answer - well explained, and links to references - but the only problem is that the OP didn't ask about *all* non-word utterances, they specified "humming", i.e. mm-mmm.

Comment: @Chappo I interpreted the question to include all non-word utterances, as some of the given examples ("Ah-huh," and "Nuh-uh") are not humming.

Comment: interesting vocable-related questions: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/221341/ https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/26175/ https://music.stackexchange.com/q/42995/